# php post file using file_get_contents does not work for some file types

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents, postdata

The following code works fine,  however if I change the files to use myFile.pdf or myFile.xlsx  the file gets created with 0 bytes.  only thing that changes for the working version and the non working version is the file type.  Why am I getting 0 bytes with excel files and pdfs?

```
 $file = file_get_contents('myFile.xml');


 $url = 'destination.php';


 $post_data = array(
     "file" => $file,
     "fileName" => "myFile.xml"
 );

$stream_options = array(
'http' => array(
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'content' => http_build_query($post_data),
),
 );

 $context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
 $response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);


 echo $response;
```

then my destination file saves the file like this:

```
 file_put_contents($_POST["fileName"], $_POST["file"]);
```

?>

Comment: I suggest you start debugging: first the steps of the above script, then you examine the actual request sent, last you check the receiving side. That is nothing we can do for you and we cannot look over your shoulders. You have to provide the debugging information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My instance the problem was actually with file size restrictions on the server and the file types were just coincidental.  check post_max_size and upload_max_filesize.